# How to make the label text on JQuery UI tabs highlightable?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, hyperlink, tabs, selectable

In the JQuery UI implementation of tabs, when a user mouses over the label text in any given tab, the cursor displays as an "I-bar" but the text itself is unselectable. That is to say, it cannot be highlighted (for purposes of copying).

For example, here's a JSFiddle containing JQuery tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/567

Notice that you cannot select the label text in the tabs themselves. I need to find a way to make the tab labels selectable.

Can this be done with JQuery UI tabs?

Comment: If you post the relevant script, html and css code you already have written and have issues with we can have a look at it and help to fix it up. In addition, creating a fiddel on jsFiddle.net can be very helpfull.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle containing JQuery tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/567/

Notice that you cannot select the label text in the tabs themselves. That's what I want to change. I want to find a way to make the tab labels selectable.

I also need to make the currently selected tab active so it will perform a page refresh on the current tab, but that's a different issue entirely.

Comment: For purpose of copying when you select the tab right click you can copy the selected tab heading. I could copy from the jsffidle link you pasted. thanks

Comment: I am able to select the tab text in firefox 14.. One way I know to disable text selection is using ``user-select: none;`` css property, but doesn't seem to apply in this case..

Answer (score 0):

It seems difficult to select the text as you have to click *outside* the clickable tab area, or your click will be `preventDefault()`ed by jquery.ui, although I don't know the exact reason for that (if there is any).

Maybe a good way to fix that would be to have a look at the `.tabs()` code, and maybe create your own version.

I usually don't like jquery.ui widgets (although I use effects and -ables) and tend to rewrite my own custom widgets depending on the specific needs of the application I'm working on; it shouldn't be hard to create a tabs behavior from scratch, so maybe it's your best opttion.